# reformat a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to transform this array :

```
<pre>
result : 

    [{
        "p": 0
      },
      {
        "p": 1
      },
      {
        "p": 2
      },
      {
        "p": 3
    }]

</pre>
```

that's what i want :

```
    {
            "p1": "1",
            "p2": "2",
            "p3": "3",
            "p4": "4",
            "p5": "5"
    }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nsgnc0/33hvf4t5/

how to do it ?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain your question a little bit more? The info provided doesn't seem sufficient

Comment: you should use a loop "for". and for each element you push it in an array with his value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this



    var modPar = {};
    for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
         modPar ['p'+i] = i;
    }

    var result = JSON.stringify(modPar);
    console.debug(result);
```

if you want i as string use

```
modPar ['p'+i] = i.toString;
```

here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jz72vL23/4/

Answer (score 1):

The format you wanted is a object not a array.

You can try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/33hvf4t5/1/

`modPar["p"+i] = i;`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```js
var orig = JSON.parse("[{\"p\":0},{\"p\":1},{\"p\":2},{\"p\":3}]");
var res = {};
for(var i=1; i<=orig.length; i++){
    res["p"+i] = orig[i-1].p;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(res));
```